# Is there a way to create a dataframe without using pd.DataFrame() function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array that needs to convert into Pandas dataframe type. However, I am not allow to use pd.Dataframe() function. Is there another a way to achieve that?

The array looks sth like this:
[("Thu Feb 27 17:23:55", 276, 67140),("Sat Feb 29 05:47:36", 376, 54980)]

array.dtype will return:
[("Date", "<U30"), ("ID", "<U30"), ("Payment", "<f8")]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: so far I can't think of a way to do it without using that function :/

Comment: Is this some sort of programming riddle? You could use `pd.read_json(json.dumps(data))` to create a DataFrame. But that function will call `pd.DataFrame` under the hood.

Comment: IMO this is a stupid task to do, in fine you will use the DataFrame constructor just implicitly. Tell your teacher to find better assignements ;)

Comment: thanks for answering this question and yes it is part of my homework question.

Comment: What other `pandas` functions have you studied, or are supposed to know about?  Homework like this only make sense in context of what you have been studying.  For example if you've been studying loading from `csv`, you could write the array to a csv (if you've studied `np.savetxt`), and then use `pd.read_csv` to load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well not sure this applies, but you can create it starting with a Series I guess:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series(arr[:, 0]).to_frame()
df[['col2', 'col3']] = arr[:, 1:]
df.columns = ['Date', 'ID', 'Payment']
```

Of course this will still use `pd.DataFrame` under the hood via the [`to_frame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) method.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering! I think it will still be considered a different way much appreciated!

Comment: @DiaryWolf yes, I think it would be a valid answer for sure. But still a weird assignment haha

Comment: no doubt haha!!